# CSS Menu aligntment acting odd in safari?

Tags: html, css, web

For some reason the menu of my site is appearing all mis-aligned when using Safari.. site is at http://penarthpc.com/~redvaner/

I've been staring at it for hours and I cant figure it out. It's driving me crazy. Below is an image of how it looks when displayed 'improperly'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFz3U.png

Below is the CSS I've written for the Navbar (element has issues)

(http)pastebin.com/kLDBGnsU

Your help is much appreciated! I'm at a wits end :(

Answer (score 0):

the only difference I can notice on first look is that your links are underlined in Safari. Everything else looks fine and not like the supplied image. The following CSS should solve the underline issue:

```
a{text-decoration:none !important;}
```

With regard to the supplied image, perhaps try adding the following to your `<li>` style

```
#nav-bar ul li{display:inline-block;zoom: 1;*display: inline;}
```

this is an ie7 fix, as inline block elements dont usually render correctly in ie7

Comment: If you repeatedly hit refresh in Safari you can re-inact the scenario